# IoT Edge hands-on lab: error with iotedgectl

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I'm working through the [Azure IoT Edge Hands-on Lab](https://github.com/AzureIoTGBB/azure-iot-edge-hol/) and running into an issue with the iotedgectl command that we can't seem to crack.

when I run 'iotedgectl status' (or 'start', or 'stop'), I get the following error message:

> File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>      "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>      exec code in run_globals
>    File "C:\Python27\Scripts\iotedgectl.exe__main__.py", line 9, in 
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl__init__.py", line 25, in >coremain
>      return cli.execute_user_command()
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\edgecli.py", line 54, in >execute_user_command
>      (is_valid, execute_deployment_cmd) = self._process_cli_args()
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\edgecli.py", line 358, in >_process_cli_args
>      return args.func(args)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\edgecli.py", line 379, in >_parse_edge_command
>      if EdgeDefault.is_deployment_supported(self._deployment):
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\default.py", line 99, in >is_deployment_supported
>      client = EdgeDockerClient()
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\edgectl\dockerclient.py", line 13, in >**init**
>      self._client = docker.DockerClient.from_env()
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 81, in from_env
>      **kwargs_from_env(**kwargs))
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 38, in **init**
>      self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
>    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 131, in >**init**
>      'Install pypiwin32 package to enable npipe:// support'
>   docker.errors.DockerException: Install pypiwin32 package to enable npipe:// >support

I'm running Docker for Windows version 17.12.0 (recent stable build), and running Linux containers.

here's my config file:

> {
>    "deployment": {
>      "docker": {
>        "edgeRuntimeImage": "microsoft/azureiotedge-agent:1.0-preview", 
>        "loggingOptions": {
>          "log-driver": "json-file", 
>          "log-opts": {
>            "max-size": "10m"
>          }
>        }, 
>        "registries": [], 
>        "uri": "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
>      }, 
>      "type": "docker"
>    }, 
>    "deviceConnectionString": "", 
>    "homeDir": "C:\ProgramData\azure-iot-edge\data", 
>    "hostName": "mygateway.local", 
>    "logLevel": "info", 
>    "schemaVersion": "1", 
>    "security": {
>      "certificates": {
>        "option": "preInstalled", 
>        "preInstalled": {
>          "agentCAPassphraseFilePath": "", 
>          "deviceCACertificateFilePath": "c:\edge\myGateway-public.pem", 
>          "deviceCAChainCertificateFilePath": "c:\edge\myGateway-all.pem", 
>          "deviceCAPassphraseFilePath": "", 
>          "deviceCAPrivateKeyFilePath": "c:\edge\myGateway-private.pem", 
>          "forceNoPasswords": false, 
>          "ownerCACertificateFilePath": "c:\edge\RootCA.pem"
>        }, 
>        "subject": {
>          "commonName": "Edge Device CA", 
>          "countryCode": "US", 
>          "locality": "Redmond", 
>          "organization": "Default Edge Organization", 
>          "organizationUnit": "Edge Unit", 
>          "state": "Washington"
>        }
>      }
>    }
>   }

Answer (score 3):

Editing my original answer:

**Problem Solution:**

- The “npipe:// broken” problem reported here applicable to Windows machines and is a problem whether Linux or Windows containers are used in Docker.
- [azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl 1.0.0rc19](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl) was released recently (Jan 26 2018) which addresses this issue by ensuring the correct pypiwin32 package is installed.
- To get the latest bits execute:

  ```
  $> pip install -U azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl
  ```
- Check installed version:

  ```
  $> iotedgectl --version
  iotedgectl 1.0.0rc19
  ```

**Summary of issue:**

- iotedgectl uses library docker-py to communicate with Docker for kick starting and controlling the Edge runtime.
- docker-py uses pypiwin32 for communicating with docker over named pipes (npipe). With the release of v222 of pypiwin32 docker-py is broken on Windows hosts.
- As a quick workaround until the official fixes can be incorporated, iotedgectl was released which ensures that correctly working dependencies get pulled in.

**Original Answer**

To operate on Windows pypiwin32 is required even if you are using Linux based containers as the docker client expects that to be present on Windows hosts.

It appears that version 222 of pypiwin32 released today (01/25/2018) seems to be causing the problem you are reporting. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32.

On my Windows 10 host pypiwin32 version 219 seems to work just fine. I would suggest installing versions below and retrying.

For Python 2.7.14

- pip install pypiwin32==219

For Python 3.6.4

- pip install pypiwin32==220

Comment: This worked for me! I used Python 2.7.14, and the command to install pypiwin32==219 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Great thanks for confirming! Just a quick note on Python 2.7.14 v220 also works. I'll update my response as well.

Comment: If could also be due to the Docker host on Windows is not running. Fixed my problem